# How to detect whether the image containing only text is blurred or not in opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have converted the pdf into jpef images and am trying to calculate whether the text images are blured or not. I have tried with laplacian filter but even for good pixelated images, it is giving different variance values. Can anyone please help me in finding whether my text image is high pixelated or low pixelated.
Thanks in advance!!

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLVXa.jpg)

for this image the laplacian variance is 322 but If I compare with multiple images of same pixel quality the value lies around 500 - 1700.

Comment: Can you provide some images?

Comment: @RahulKedia I have updated the image. Take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to threshhold the image at different values then compare the count of white pixels. For example,

- If the text was clear and black then the results of non zeros  pixels would be very similar for img1 and img2.
- If img was blurred then the difference would be larger.

  ```
    import cv2
    image_path = r"d:\temp\xLVXa.jpg"
    imgColor = cv2.imread(image_path)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(imgColor, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret1, img1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    ret2, img2 = cv2.threshold(img,192,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    whitepixels1 = cv2.countNonZero(img1)
    whitepixels2 = cv2.countNonZero(img2)

    print("img1 white pixels - %d" % whitepixels1)
    print("img2 white pixels - %d" % whitepixels2)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I don't have multiple images of same type to compare. I have been given text images of different types and I want to predict whether it is good pixelated or not.

Comment: You don't need multiple images. Just threshhold the same image using 2 values then compare

Comment: Okie. Thank you so much.. I will try that way

Comment: If this is helps you please could you accept my answer? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "very similar"? Is there a number for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not blurred. On the opposite it is very sharp and scrambled, so that any test based on a low gradient strength will fail.

Some of the characters seem "textured" and I think you could detect an abnormal density of corners (using a corner detector). Some are not much damaged and are forever impossible to tell from valid characters.